# How do I remove vertical scroll using DT library in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio, dt, rnotebook

[what I have right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDzOq.png)
I am trying to display the first six observations of my data set, but since I have 79 variables the columns don't fit all in one line. I managed to add a horizontal scroll bar using the DT library (so now the output chunk is a table where the columns appear all on one line). The problem is that I now have also a vertical scroll bar which I don't want: as you can see in the image one needs to scroll down also to see all six observations. Is there a way to display the six rows and scroll to the right to see the 79 variables? i.e. can I keep only the horizontal scroll bar and remove the vertical?

edit: [I solved it like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYUUO.png)

Comment: have you tried `option=list(pageLength=6)` ?

Comment: @fra yes, it doesn't change anything